# Get Image File Size From Base64 String

Tags: python, image

I'm working on a python web service.
It calls another web service to change the picture of a profile.

It connects to another web service.
This web service can only accept pictures that are 4 MB or smaller.

I will put the checking in the first web service.
It uses PIL to check if the base64 string is a valid image.
However, how do I check if the base64 string will create a 4 MB or smaller image?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Multiply the length of the data by 3/4, since encoding turns 6 bytes into 8. If the result is within a few bytes of 4MB then you'll need to count the number of `=` at the end.

Comment: @Rob: It's always very approximately true. The data is padded with `=` to bring it to a certain block size, but the expansion of the data itself does follow this.

Comment: @ChemicalProgrammer: It returns whatever unit you put into it.

Answer (score 11):

I'm using this:

```
def size(b64string):
    return (len(b64string) * 3) / 4 - b64string.count('=', -2)
```

We remove the length of the padding, which is either zero, one, or two characters `=`, as [explained here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Probably not optimal. I don't know how efficient `str.count(char)` is. On the other hand, it is only performed on a string of length 2.

Answer (score -1):

image size can be calculated from the string length.
Since every character represents 6 bits and every '=' sign shows lack of 8 bits. 
[ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

```
file_size = (len(base64_string) * 6 - base64_string.count('=') * 8) / 8
```

or

```
file_size = len(base64_string) * 3 / 4 - base64_string.count('=')
```

will give the file size in byte and,
dividing it in mega(=1000000) will give the file size in megabyte