# how to get image name and image size from base64 string image

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I am working on mobile app development. I am uploading image in base64 string format. i want image name and image size from base64 image string.

```
$("body").append("<img id='hiddenImage' src='" + "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData + "' />");
var file_size = $('#hiddenImage').size();
alert(file_size);
var width = $('#hiddenImage').width();
var height = $('#hiddenImage').height();
$('#hiddenImage').remove();
alert("width:" + width + " height:" + height);
```

Comment: You need to get the dimensions after successful load. You cannot get a name. Also why append when you remove it anyway? Just keep it in memory

Comment: Hey Madhavi

You can calculate the file size from base64 string.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761889/get-image-file-size-from-base64-string

However, I have never heard of getting filename from the same.

In case you're using <input type="file"/> to select file, then its easy to  get all the details using HTML5 FileReader.

Comment: Here is how to get the dimensions: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/jnu8eu2w/