# How do I check the size of a file in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, base64, buffer, filesize

So, I have a file (jpg, tiff or pdf) which initially is represented as a base64-encoded string, which I create a buffer from.

Now I want to check the size of given file **without** writing it to filesystem first.

I am using Node v4.4.3 on Linux.

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: Where are you getting the file from? Multer or somewhere else?

Comment: I updated the question. File is being transferred base64-encoded, as string. I am not using Express.

Comment: You may approximately get size of your file.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761889/get-image-file-size-from-base64-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Buffer.byteLength](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_bytelength_string_encoding) function.

Comment: Thanks, this works!I was searching for 'size' instead of 'length' in the documentation of Buffer ..