# how to check image size before download

Tags: python, image, size

I have image at url as below:

```
http://ipcamera-viewer.com/image/?p=199619_20170221_162149_7208.jpg
```

Because I can't download it easily so I used way like this

```
browser.get(urlServer)
browser.save_screenshot(pathLocal)
```

I don't want to download image only black that size is small, so I want to check the file size, I tried to use

```
imgData = browser.get_get_screenshot_as_base64()
if len(imgData) > 5000: browser.save_screenshot(pathLocal)
```

But base64 is not the same as image size, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761889/get-image-file-size-from-base64-string) question may provide some insight. It says to multiply by .75 to get an estimated result of the size of the image in bytes which you can compare to.

```
if (len(imgData)*.75) > desiredBytes: browser.save_screenshot(pathLocal)
```

Comment: Hahaha I adjusted my answer accordingly, glad to help!!

Comment: By the way, can you tell me why?

Comment: The previous question said that when an image is encoded to base64 it converts 6 bytes to 8 bytes which is why they say to multiply it by .75 in order to negate that conversion to get an estimate for the number of bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your patient answer:) can you answer my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42419481/how-to-convert-save-base64-to-image-in-python ?  @Darnell