# How to Convert save_base64 to Image in Python

Tags: python, image, rotation, base64, screenshot

I use code as below to download Image with query string, it is no any problems.

```
urlServer = "http://ipcamera-viewer.com/image/?p=199619_20170221_162149_7208.jpg"
browser.get(urlServer)
imgData = browser.get_screenshot_as_base64()
size = int(len(imgData) * 0.75)
if size > minSizeImage:
    browser.save_screenshot(pathLocal)
```

now I want to rotate the image before save to file, can I use code

```
urlServer = "http://ipcamera-viewer.com/image/?p=199619_20170221_162149_7208.jpg"
browser.get(urlServer)
imgBase64= browser.get_screenshot_as_base64()
imgBytes = BytesIO(base64.b64decode(imgBase64))
imgData = PIL.Image.open(imgBytes)
size = int(len(imgBase64) / 8)
if size > minSizeImage:
    imgData = imgData.rotate(angle, expand = True)
    imgData.save(pathLocal)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick, rather then saving just to read it in again. Didn't get the chance to try this out though.

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import base64


im = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(imgData)))
im = im.rotate(45)
im.save(pathLocal)
```

Comment: Great! that is what I need! one more problem, size = int(len(imgData) * 0.75) is not correct, so how can I get im size in bytes?

Comment: I found a way to get size in bytes, but I am not sure why.... check modified code above...

Answer (score 0):

With the PIL Image module you can do like this

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("bride.jpg")
im = im.rotate(45)
```

Comment: That should be done after save to file, but I want to do it before save...